# Calculate the number of paths in a grid from top left to bottom right

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, pruning

I need to calculate the number of paths from top left to right bottom where a valid path is path that crosses all the squares in the grid (and exactly once for every square)

I'm using the backtracking technique. Unfortunately, `count` is `0` in the end of the calculation. Printing `t`, I see that it never gets to `n-1`.

What's wrong with my algorithm?

```
n = 4
count = 0
m = [[False for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)] 

def num_of_paths(m, x, y, t):

    print(t)

    global count

    # check if we reached target
    if x == (n - 1) and y == (n - 1):
        if t < (n * n):
            # not on time, prune the tree here
            return 
        elif t == n * n:
            # completed a full path in the grid and on time
            count += 1 

    if t > n * n:
        return

    # Right
    if x + 1 < n and m[x + 1][y] == False:
        m[x + 1][y] = True
        num_of_paths(m, x + 1, y, t + 1)
        m[x + 1][y] = False

    # Left
    if x - 1 > 0 and m[x - 1][y] == False:
        m[x - 1][y] = True
        num_of_paths(m, x - 1, y, t + 1)
        m[x - 1][y] = False

    # Down
    if y + 1 < n and m[x][y + 1] == False:
        m[x][y + 1] = True
        num_of_paths(m, x, y + 1, t + 1)
        m[x][y + 1] = False

    # Up
    if y - 1 > 0 and m[x][y - 1] == False:
        m[x][y - 1] = True
        num_of_paths(m, x, y - 1, t + 1)
        m[x][y - 1] = False


num_of_paths(m, 0, 0, 0)
print(count)
```

Comment: There are several problems, but the main one is *there are no valid paths in an even-sized square grid*, so you can debug it until cows come home.

Comment: What are the other problems? (it's `0` also for `n=5`)

Comment: Well try starting with n=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The starting cell is not marked with `m[0][0] = True`, so after going right, the algorithm will go left again, and actually visit that cell twice. To resolve this, you can move the code for managing the `m` values away from where you have it now (4 times) and apply it to the *current* cell (once). This includes the `if m[..][..]` check, and the assignments of `True` and `False`.
- The `if` conditions that relate to the left and up directions should compare the coordinate with `>= 0`, not with `> 0`: a zero value for a coordinate is still within range.
- `t` should start with 1, since you compare its value with `n * n`. Or else you should compare with `n * n - 1`. In my correction below I will start with `t = 1`.
- Not a real problem, but after doing `count += 1` it would make sense to immediately `return`, since there is no possibility anymore to extend the path further.

Some other remarks:

- When *n* is even, there is no valid path, so even when corrected, the function is bound to return 0 in that case
- The number of paths this algorithm visits is exponential, *O(2<sup>n²</sup>)*. For *n > 6*, don't wait for it...

Here is a corrected version of your code. Comments should clarify what was changed and why:

```
n = 5
count = 0
m = [[False for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)] 

def num_of_paths(m, x, y, t):
    global count
    # Moved the "visited" check to here. No need to add `== True`.
    if m[x][y]: 
        return
    if x == (n - 1) and y == (n - 1):
        if t < (n * n):
            return 
        else: # Removed the unnecessary condition here
            count += 1 
            # Added a return here
            return
    # Removed an if-block of which the condition could never be true
    # Moved the "visited" marking to here:
    m[x][y] = True
    if x + 1 < n:
        num_of_paths(m, x + 1, y, t + 1)
    # Corrected "> 0" to ">= 0"
    if x - 1 >= 0:
        num_of_paths(m, x - 1, y, t + 1)
    if y + 1 < n:
        num_of_paths(m, x, y + 1, t + 1)
    # Corrected "> 0" to ">= 0"
    if y - 1 >= 0:
        num_of_paths(m, x, y - 1, t + 1)
    # Moved the "visited" unmarking to here:
    m[x][y] = False

# Corrected the last argument
num_of_paths(m, 0, 0, 1)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is working

```
n = 3
count=0
m = [[False for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)] 

def num_of_paths(m,x,y):


    # setting (x,y) position in m = True as we have crossed this square now


    m[y][x]=True
    global count
    # check if we reached target

    if x == (n - 1) and y == (n - 1):

        # check if we haven't missed any square

        for i in m:   
            if False in i:
                m[y][x]=False
                return 

        # increment count if we visited all squares

        count+=1    
        m[y][x]=False
        return 


     # setting up legel directions in which current point(x,y) should head next
    dir={'up','down','left','right'}
    if x==0:
        dir-={'left'}
    if x==n-1:
        dir-={'right'}
    if y==0:
        dir-={'up'}
    if y==n-1:
        dir-={'down'}
    # now we have all legal directions that (x,y) could go to

    # now iterate over all possible directions of (x,y)
    for i in dir:
        if i=='left':      # left means (x,y) will change to (x-1,y) i.e. change is (-1,0)
            if m[y][x-1]==False:   # it means left of (x,y) havent yet crossed i.e. it is legel to visit now
                num_of_paths(m,x-1,y)
    # similiarly for other possible directions

        if i=='right':
            if m[y][x+1]==False:
                num_of_paths(m,x+1,y)

        if i=='up':
            if m[y-1][x]==False:
                num_of_paths(m,x,y-1)

        if i=='down':
            if m[y+1][x]==False:
                num_of_paths(m,x,y+1)


num_of_paths(m,0,0)
print(count)
```

let me know if there is some issue